# Ant design 4 table loading not working properly

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

Im using my react project for ant design 4,  i added table loading for loading, I have some conflict added loaded not working, anyone know how to fix that issue?
Thanks

code here

[Here the stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hjsyrz?file=index.jsfontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
       const columns = [
      {
        title: "Name",
        dataIndex: "name",
        key: "name",
        render: text => <a href="javascript:;">{text}</a>
      },
      {
        title: "Age",
        dataIndex: "age",
        key: "age"
      },
      {
        title: "Address",
        dataIndex: "address",
        key: "address"
      },
      {
        title: "Tags",
        key: "tags",
        dataIndex: "tags",
        render: tags => (
          <span>
            {tags.map(tag => {
              let color = tag.length > 5 ? "geekblue" : "green";
              if (tag === "loser") {
                color = "volcano";
              }
              return (
                <Tag color={color} key={tag}>
                  {tag.toUpperCase()}
                </Tag>
              );
            })}
          </span>
        )
      },
      {
        title: "Action",
        key: "action",
        render: (text, record) => (
          <span>
            <a href="javascript:;">Invite {record.name}</a>
            <Divider type="vertical" />
            <a href="javascript:;">Delete</a>
          </span>
        )
      }
    ];
    
    
    
    class App extends React.Component {
      state = {
        data: [],
        pagination: {
          current: 1,
          pageSize: 10
        },
        loading: true
      };
    
      componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.setState({ loading: false });
        }, 1000);
      }
    
      render() {
        const data = [
          {
            key: "1",
            name: "John Brown",
            age: 32,
            address: "New York No. 1 Lake Park",
            tags: ["nice", "developer"]
          },
          {
            key: "2",
            name: "Jim Green",
            age: 42,
            address: "London No. 1 Lake Park",
            tags: ["loser"]
          },
          {
            key: "3",
            name: "Joe Black",
            age: 32,
            address: "Sidney No. 1 Lake Park",
            tags: ["cool", "teacher"]
          }
        ];
        return (
          <Table
            columns={columns}
            dataSource={data}
            loading={this.state.loading}
            onChange={this.handleTableChange}
          />
        );
      }
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: make loading false once data load in your case data is static then make loading false on timeout on specific interval

Comment: @DivyeshKanzariya Hi, Look at my updated question

Comment: now seems working